# ISNUMERIC() does not work for decimals

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, isnumeric

I am using the SQL Server 2008 R2 function ISNUMERIC() to determine if a string is a decimal or not.
It is returning '1' when the decimal as a comma or comma and period.  I can fix for those issues but this query is part of a SSRS Report that will be distributed among many users and I cannot correct of all problems.

What can I use instead of ISNUMERIC() to determine if the string is a correctly formed decimal?  I cannot use TRY_PARSE() because that is available in SQL SERVER 2012 and I am on 2008 R2.

**UPDATE**
I want to replace ISNUMERIC() with PATINDEX() to identify decimals.
Both of these examples return 0

```
SELECT PATINDEX('9,0', '%[0-9]%.%[0-9]%')
SELECT PATINDEX('9.0', '%[0-9]%.%[0-9]%')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your objective? Why don't you want to use ISNUMERIC()?

Comment: It doesn't work.  Initially, I was using ISNUMERIC().  This function was returning 'true' for string values of '9,.7' After doing some searching, it was  stated that this function should not be used.  If you are on SQL 2012, you can use TRY_PARSE() but I using SQL 2008.

Comment: To get definitive matching functionality I don't think there is any other way than using regular expressions. This feature is not available as a standard option SQL Sever 2008. However, it can be added. I would rate this as intermediate to advanced technique. If you are able to figure this out, your SQL Server Admin/DBA might say "No way!" Here are a few links with a various approaches to the same solution, regular expression support within SQL Server 2008.

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/

Comment: Another method. https://www.codeproject.com/articles/42764/regular-expressions-in-ms-sql-server-2005-2008

Comment: And one more. This is one that I got to work for me. https://blogs.sap.com/2013/01/31/regular-expressions-within-a-crystal-report/

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter values for PATINDEX are reverse. This should work for you...

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%[0-9]%,%[0-9]%', '9,0')
SELECT PATINDEX('%[0-9]%.%[0-9]%', '9.0')
```

Noel

Comment: Duh!  Thanks!  But if I want to include whole numbers too would I have just add an `OR` to the query or is there a way to change the pattern?

Comment: You need to add an OR @GloriaSantin

Comment: I think you are going to have to use an OR within a CASE statement. Something like this...

SELECT
    CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[0-9]%.%[0-9]%', '9.0') = 1
              OR PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', '9') = 1 THEN 1
         ELSE 0
    END

Comment: Thanks. I will try that because putting the `or` in the `where` clause ain't working.

Comment: It is still throwing an error when the string `value` is attempting to convert to a number when it is not.  So, the value passes the `PATINDEX` function when it is not a number.